# Running head fix using endnotes.sty

Tags: endnotes

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{endnotes}%
\let\footnote\endnote%

\usepackage{endheads}

\begin{document}

\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname}}

\def\enotesize{\normalsize}%
\def\enoteformat{%
\parskip=9pt
\ignorespaces\leavevmode{\makeenmark}\ignorespaces\ \ignorespaces%
}%%

Test\label{endnote1}\footnote{Endnote 1}
Any project\footnote{Endnote 2} that has gestated as long as this one
must, of necessity, also accrue enormous debts to mentors, collaborators, inspirators, students, and friends who have contributed to our thinking and our work. Principal among them are.\footnote{Endnote 3}

XYZ took on the role\footnote{Endnote 4} of an {amicus curiae} for the first draft of this,
going thorough our text in thoughtful detail\footnote{Endnote 5} and
improving both what was presented and the clarity of the presentation. We have not words enough to thank him.\footnote{Endnote 6}

Test\footnote{Endnote 7}
Any project\footnote{Endnote 8} that has gestated as long as this one
must, of necessity, also accrue enormous debts to mentors,
collaborators, inspirators, students, and friends who have
contributed to our thinking and our work. Principal among them are.\footnote{Endnote 9}

XYZ took on the role\footnote{Endnote 10} of an {amicus curiae} for the first draft of this,
going thorough our text in thoughtful detail\footnote{Endnote 11} and
improving both what was presented and the clarity of the
presentation. We have not words enough to thank him.\footnote{Endnote
12}

Test\footnote{Endnote 13}
Any project\footnote{Endnote 14} that has gestated as long as this one
must, of necessity, also accrue enormous debts to mentors,
collaborators, inspirators, students, and friends who have
contributed to our thinking and our work. Principal among them
are.\footnote{Endnote 15}

XYZ took on the role\footnote{Endnote 16} of an {amicus curiae} for the first draft of this,
going thorough our text in thoughtful detail\footnote{Endnote 17} and
improving both what was presented and the clarity of the
presentation. We have not words enough to thank him.\footnote{Endnote
18}

\clearpage

Test\footnote{Endnote 19}
Any project\footnote{Endnote 20} that has gestated as long as this one
must, of necessity, also accrue enormous debts to mentors,
collaborators, inspirators, students, and friends who have
contributed to our thinking and our work. Principal among them
are.\footnote{Endnote 21}

XYZ took on the role\footnote{Endnote 22} of an {amicus curiae} for the first draft of this,
going thorough our text in thoughtful detail\footnote{Endnote 23} and
improving both what was presented and the clarity of the
presentation. We have not words enough to thank him.\footnote{Endnote
24}

Test\footnote{Endnote 25}
Any project\footnote{Endnote 26} that has gestated as long as this one
must, of necessity, also accrue enormous debts to mentors,
collaborators, inspirators, students, and friends who have
contributed to our thinking and our work. Principal among them
are.\label{endnote27}\footnote{Endnote 27}


\clearpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

I've found that `endheads.sty` does the tricks, but if I use that package some errors are coming, can any one advise what mistake I did? please...

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @PeterWilson I need the running head as `Notes to Pages 000--000` ' I tried but couldn't please help

Comment: But that is what processing your MWE gives. I don't understand what is it that you are after?

Comment: @PeterWilson Sorry, today only I came back, now I've reproduced the tag which gave some error, and I need the running head should be `Notes to Pages 000–000` to both sides, please advise...

Comment: I'm unclear as to what a "tag" is. To me it looks like an "MWE".

Comment: I thought that you might respond to my answer. I hope you are well and have access to this site.

Comment: @PeterWilson Yes, I'm fine and well and thanks, I'm on my holidays in my native, don''t have computer, will get back in a day or two...

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what you want in the end.

Try not using the `endheads` package and then at the end of your document:

```
\clearpage
\markboth{Notes to Pages 000-000}{Notes to Pages 000-000}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

which will put "Notes to Pages 000-000" in the heading of both recto and verso pages. If you want the "Notes ..." twice on top of a page then use the fancyhdr` package macros appropriately.

PS. the `endheads` package requires some other packages to do its work, which you did not call for.